# Read data attribute from cloned input returns value from the initial input

Tags: jquery

In the form I have a `select` option and each option has a `data` attribute.

On `change` I am getting the value of `data-size` from the selected option and I am filling the neighbor's input. This works fine.

Now, I added a plus button, which clones the row, which works fine too.

However, when I select an option (from the cloned row) the `var row = $(this).data("row");` returns always `1`, which belongs to the first row.. So every time, it updates the first row input, and not its neighbor's.

What am I missing here?

```js
var counter = 1;
$('#myform')
  .on('click', '.addInput', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var $template = $('.copy-row').slice(-1).clone(true, true).find('input').end()
      .find('.addInput').removeClass('addInput').addClass('removeInput').text('-').end()
      .find('[name^="cloth-"]').attr('name', 'cloth-' + counter).attr('tabindex', counter).val(null).attr('data-row', counter).end()
      .find('[name^="size-"]').attr('name', 'size-' + counter).attr('tabindex', counter).val("").end()
    $template.insertAfter('.copy-row:last');
    $('.copy-row:last').focus();

  })
  // Remove button click handler
  .on('click', '.removeInput', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $row = $('.copy-row').slice(-1);
    counter--;
    $row.remove();
  });

$('#myform')
  .on('change', '.getclothsize', function(e) {
    var size = $(this).find('option:selected').data("size");
    var row = $(this).data("row");
    console.log("size " + size + " from row = " + row);
    if (size != null) {
      $("input[name='size-" + row + "']").val(size);
    }
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<form id="myform">
  <div class="form-row copy-row mb-3">
    <div class="form-group col-3">
      <select name="cloth-1" data-row="1" class="custom-select getclothsize">
        <option></option>
        <option value="option1" data-size="M">option1</option>
        <option value="option2" data-size="L">option2</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-2">
      <input name="size-1" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-2">
      <button class="btn btn-primary addInput">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is because the line of code where you update the `val()` of the `size` inputs is selecting *all* of the inputs in the DOM, not just the one related to the `select` which was changed.

You can fix this by using `closest()` to get a reference of the row then using `find()` to get the `input`, something like this:

```
const $row = $(this).closest('.form-row');
$row.find('input').val('foo');
```

However, it's worth noting that you can improve the logic. Using a 'counter' variable to dynamically increment `input` names, or to add `data` attributes which match the index of a row is a big code smell.

A better approach is to us the same `name` on all the form controls and handle them as an array when submitted to the server. You can also use DOM traversal to relate the inputs in the same row to each other.

Here's a working example with these updates applied:

```js
const $form = $('#myform');

$form.on('click', '.addInput', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const $template = $('.copy-row').first().clone(true, true);
  $template.find('.addInput').toggleClass('addInput removeInput').text('-');
  $template.find('input').val(null);
  $template.insertAfter('.copy-row:last');
  $('.copy-row:last').focus();
});

$form.on('click', '.removeInput', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.form-row').remove();
});

$form.on('change', '.getclothsize', function(e) {
  const $el = $(this);
  const $row = $el.closest('.form-row');
  const size = $el.find('option:selected').data("size");
  
  console.log("size " + size + " from row = " + $row.index());
  
  if (size) {
    $row.find("input[name='size']").val(size);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<form id="myform">
  <div class="form-row copy-row mb-3">
    <div class="form-group col-3">
      <select name="cloth" class="custom-select getclothsize">
        <option></option>
        <option value="option1" data-size="M">option1</option>
        <option value="option2" data-size="L">option2</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-2">
      <input name="size" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-2">
      <button class="btn btn-primary addInput">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the additional info! I learned something more today  :)